# Pass the same file to several parallel unix commands that all run different Perl scripts

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing

I have several different perl scripts that I am running simultaneously. All of them take the same text file as input (`textfile.txt`). Is there a way that I could write the file name once instead of writing it several times?

```
$ perl myscript1.pl textfile.txt & perl myscript2.pl textfile.txt & 
perl myscript3.pl textfile.txt & perl myscript4.pl textfile.txt & 
perl myscript5.pl textfile.txt & perl myscript6.pl textfile.txt & 
perl myscript7.pl textfile.txt & perl myscript8.pl textfile.txt
```

Comment: Write one more script, that invokes all the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel perl {} textfile.txt ::: myscript*.pl
```

Run with `parallel --dry-run ...` first if you want to see what it would do, but without actually doing anything.

Note that if you have 4 CPU cores, it will start 4 jobs in parallel and then start a new one each time a job finishes, and that is subtly different from having all running at once. If you have, say 32 jobs but only 4 cores and all 32 should be running at once, use `parallel -j 32 ...` for example.

Comment: What a neat way of using parallel. Exactly what I was looking for; a simple, clever one-liner. I have two more questions however: `1.` If I have 50 CPU cores and 100 jobs, but only want to run 32 jobs at once, will parallel -j 32 achieve that for me? `2.` What would I change in the code above if I had more text files and I wanted all of them to be passed to all of my perl scripts?

Comment: It's actually quite fitting - given that **GNU Parallel** is itself a Perl script. 1) yes. 2) `parallel perl {} p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 ::: script*.pl`

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work for me. It generates all combinations of each perl script with `all` of the text files (e.g. first one generated is `perl script1.pl p1.txt p2.txt p3.txt p4.txt p5.txt p6.txt`. But I realized that replacing `{}` with `:::` instead works! But I have to also exchange the place of scripts with the text files, therefore: `parallel --dry-run perl ::: script*.pl ::: text1.txt text2.txt text3.txt text4.txt`. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
run_all_perl() (
    perl_scripts=(
      myscript1.pl  myscript2.pl  myscript3.pl  myscript4.pl
      myscript5.pl  myscript6.pl  myscript7.pl  myscript8.pl
    )
    for script in "${perl_scripts[@]}"; do
        perl "$script" "$1" &
    done
    wait
)

run_all_perl textfile.txt
```